# Multiple inputs for paypal form?

Tags: html, wordpress, forms, paypal

I have this code for a paypal form. It has 2 inputs: a text box and a select. Either one included in the code without each other works fine. When they are both included, it takes which ever one is on bottom. Is there a way to make it so that they are both valid, and will be added together if someone fills in both inputs?

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="paypal">
<input name="cmd" type="hidden" value="_xclick" /> 
<input name="business" type="hidden" value="RU48JVL7LR94Y" /> 
<input name="item_name" type="hidden" value="Donation" />
<table>
<tr>
<td><strong>Donation of any amount</strong></td>
<td></td>
<td><input maxlength="60" name="amount" size="40" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>Send A Kid to Camp</strong></td>
<td></td>
<td><select name="amount">
<option value="0">$0</option>
<option value="250">1 Kid - $250</option>
<option value="500">2 Kids - $500</option>
<option value="750">3 Kids - $750</option>
<option value="1000">4 Kids - $1000</option>
<option value="1250">5 Kids - $1250</option>
<option value="1500">6 Kids - $1500</option>
<option value="1750">7 Kids - $1750</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Comments:</td>
<td></td>
<input type="hidden" name="on3" value="Notes">
<td><textarea name="os3" rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Notes" wrap></textarea></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<input name="currency_code" type="hidden" value="USD" /> <input alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" name="submit" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donate_LG.gif" type="image" /> <img src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/WEBSCR-640-20110306-1/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" alt="" width="1" height="1" border="0" />

</form>
```

Comment: well thats what happens when you call your form inputs the same name....change it to name="amount1" & name="amount2"

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with some Client-side scripting. I have used Jquery .

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        var selected_val = $('#select_val').val();
        var donate_text_box_val = $('#donate_text_box_amount').val();
        var total = (+selected_val) + (+donate_text_box_val);
        $('#final_amount').val(total);
    });

});

</script>
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="paypal">
<input name="cmd" type="hidden" value="_xclick" /> 
<input name="business" type="hidden" value="RU48JVL7LR94Y" /> 
<input name="item_name" type="hidden" value="Donation" />
<table>
<tr>
<td><strong>Donation of any amount</strong></td>
<td></td>
<td><input maxlength="60" id="donate_text_box_amount" name="donate_text_box_amount" value="" size="40" type="text" /></td>
<td><input id="final_amount" name="amount" value="" size="40" type="hidden" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>Send A Kid to Camp</strong></td>
<td></td>
<td><select id="select_val">
<option value="0">$0</option>
<option value="250">1 Kid - $250</option>
<option value="500">2 Kids - $500</option>
<option value="750">3 Kids - $750</option>
<option value="1000">4 Kids - $1000</option>
<option value="1250">5 Kids - $1250</option>
<option value="1500">6 Kids - $1500</option>
<option value="1750">7 Kids - $1750</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Comments:</td>
<td></td>
<input type="hidden" name="on3" value="Notes">
<td><textarea name="os3" rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Notes" wrap></textarea></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<input name="currency_code" type="hidden" value="USD" /> 
<input id="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" name="submit" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donate_LG.gif" type="image" /> 
<img src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/WEBSCR-640-20110306-1/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" alt="" width="1" height="1" border="0" />

</form>
```

Basically, you will need to dynamically populate the `amount` parameter and pass it to PayPal.